# i am using flutter for chat app and getting an error in user distinguish for receiver and sender

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class Messages extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,// here is the error " The argument type 'User' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<dynamic>'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)"
```

builder: (ctx, futureSnapshot) {
if (futureSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
return Center(
child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
);
}

```
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('chat')
                .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (ctx, chatSnapshot) {
              if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data.docs;
              return ListView.builder(
                reverse: true,
                itemCount: chatSnapshot.data.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => MessageBubble(
                  chatDocs[index]['text'],
                  chatDocs[index]['userId'] == futureSnapshot.data.uid,
                  key: ValueKey(chatDocs[index].documentID),
                ),
              );
            });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add error message.

Comment: `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is not a future, it returns the current authenticated user as an instance of `User` class or null.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

'FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser' is not a future to get the current user uid you can do this instead.

```
class Messages extends StatelessWidget {
final User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 final uid = user.uid; // set the function here
 return StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('chat')
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (ctx, chatSnapshot) {
      if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
      final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data.docs;
      return ListView.builder(
        reverse: true,
        itemCount: chatSnapshot.data.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => MessageBubble(
          chatDocs[index]['text'],
          chatDocs[index]['userId'] == uid, // Use it here
          key: ValueKey(chatDocs[index].documentID),
        ),
      );
    });
}
}
```

Comment: The instance member 'user' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Comment: this error is showing when using the abov code

Comment: @MrRock Sorry about that, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser is not a Future like the error says. It returns an instance of User Class if the user is authenticated. You don't need to use FutureBuilder Widget for this situation. You can directly use it.